# I am experiencing an error when running my flutter project on `ios` simulator In Flutter (vs code)

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I am experiencing an error on my flutter project when running it on the `ios` simulator and hence I am unable to run my project on the simulator, I have tried erasing all content and settings on the simulator and tried running flutter clean and rm ios/podfile and upgraded my packages and updated my podfile it still doesn't work. The error follows:-

```
error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/Alan/Downloads/fluttershare/ios/GoogleService-Info.plist' (in target

'Runner' from project 'Runner')

note: Using new build system

note: Building targets in parallel

note: Planning build

note: Constructing build description

warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 6.0, but the range of supported

deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.7.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')

warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team

ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported

deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.7.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates' from project 'Pods')

warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported

deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.7.99. (in target 'Protobuf' from project 'Pods')

warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 4.3, but the range of supported

deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.7.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')

warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported

deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.7.99. (in target 'GTMSessionFetcher' from project 'Pods')

warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 4.3, but the range of supported

deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.7.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')

warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 5.0, but the range of supported

deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.7.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')

warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported

deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.7.99. (in target 'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')

warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 5.0, but the range of supported

deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.7.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')

warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported

deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.7.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')

warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported

deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.7.99. (in target 'GTMAppAuth' from project 'Pods')

warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported

deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.7.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')

warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 6.0, but the range of supported

deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.7.99. (in target 'GoogleAppMeasurement' from project 'Pods')
```

Could not build the application for the simulator.

Error launching application on iPhone 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you download and add the `GoogleService-Info.plist` from Firebase to your app in the following location:

[image]

Comment: How to get GoogleService-Info.plist?? Also i am using Visual studio code not xcode for my programming

Comment: @SaiPrashanth you need to have xcode in order to get that file, as an account for developers is needed to get the file: [more here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=pt)